# Execute local sh-script from local HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, sh

I want to make and run a local HTML page (through `file:///pathToFile/index.html`).

This page will have a button. When pressed, a shell script located on my local file system next to the HTML page will be executed.

I tried:
`<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="window.open('./test.sh')" />`

But the browser offers me to download the shell script instead of executing it.

How can I make the webpage execute a script locally, and get the result of the execution in a variable?

Comment: It could be possible if you put your page inside an Electron shell.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that! Intentionally! Web page runs in its own sandbox and is not able to interact with your system bellow. Otherwise everyone could run anything on your machine (infect your system, delete files, etc.)

Comment: I am not talking about a webpage that would be available on the internet, only a local html file, trying to execute a local script sitting right next to it in the same file system

Comment: By design, the browser can not do this.  have a look at the answer from @A-Tech

Answer (score -1):

With plain JS it is not possible.
You can exectute script from the server side (which would be your machine) with [`php`](https://www.php.net/). Using the `shell_exec()`-command.

Do note that you need to install/start a webserver with php locally!

Comment: As it stands the answer is half an answer and a comment.  Please edit it and show some of the php with shell_exec with arguments.